# Kendo Grid Server Side Filtering with MVC

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a grid with Web Api server side sorting, which works. I have a requirement to add filtering. When the grid's datasource sends the filtering arguments to the Web Api controller, the Filter object is always 'empty', not null. Here is my setup

Grid datasource:

```
var myTeamGridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    serverPaging: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    schema: {
        data: "data",
        total: "count"
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: baseMyTeamUrl, // web api
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",               
        }
    },       
    sort: {
        field: "Name",
        dir: "asc"
    }
});
```

The Action:

```
public HttpResponseMessage KendoGridMyTeam(GridInputModel inputModel)
{
     ... 
}
```

GridInputModel.cs

```
public class GridInputModel
{
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public int PageSize { get; set; }
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public List<GridInputSortModel> Sort { get; set; }
    public List<GridInputFilterModel> Filter { get; set; }
}
```

GridInputFilterModel.cs

```
public class GridInputFilterModel
{
    public GridInputFilterModel()
    {
        filters = new List<GridInputFilterModel>();
    }
    public string field { get; set; }
    public string Operator { get; set; }
    public object value { get; set; }
    public string logic { get; set; }
    public List<GridInputFilterModel> filters { get; set; }

}
```

The Request Body

```
    take=10&skip=0&page=1&pageSize=10&sort[0][field]=Name&sort[0][dir]=asc
&filter[filters][0][field]=Name
&filter[filters][0][operator]=eq
&filter[filters][0][value]=cling
&filter[logic]=and
```

The GridInputModel "GridInputModel inputModel" is instantiated, and the sort object is preset and that feature works just fine. But the filter, when set in the client and sent to the server is empty. After a bunch of searching, I cannot find a modern example of server side grid filtering. You may suggest that I use the Kendo.Mvc library with:

```
[DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request
```

This ALSO creates a Filter object in the Request but the filters are also empty. Any suggestions? One option, that I would hesitate to use, is to use parameterMap and send the filter along on the querystring. If I have to, fine, but somebody has to have this working.

Answer (score 1):

Whats happening is that your application serverside isn't deserializing the filter objects properly. You can view this if you set the parameter to an object and view the actual JSON that is sent. Your filter will be present in the string. Use Parameter map and format the filter array before its sent and you might one to overload the DataSourceClass that kendo uses. I had the same issue and had to create my own class and format the filters before sending. The issue that messing up your filters is the operator property in the filter array.

Answer (score 1):

In your javascript try this:

```
var grid = $("#YourGridId").data("kendoGrid");
var $filter = new Array();
$filter.push({ field: "Name", operator: "eq", value: "cling" });
grid.dataSource.filter($filter);
```

and in your controller method you need this signature:

```
public ActionResult ReadData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using MVC instead of WebApi, but I was getting the same symptom of a null filter passed to my controller method. I, too, went down the rabbit hole of creating my own model to handle the request parameter sent to my controller method, trying to parse Kendo's filter structure, etc. I finally got it to work by following [this example](https://blog.falafel.com/server-paging-sorting-filtering-kendo-datasourcerequest/) on Falafel's blog. Specifically, you need to make the changes listed below to your code.

In the end, the technique shown below makes it very easy to implement server processing for Kendo's DataSource (once you know all the required pieces to make it work).

Grid DataSource: You have to match all the (case-sensitive) fields coming back from the server. I left out errors, and it stopped working. You may have to change the type to get it working with WebApi.

```
type: "aspnetmvc-ajax",
schema: {
    data: "Data",
    total: "Total",
    errors: "Errors",
    model: {
        id: "YourKeyFieldName"
    }
},
```

The Action: Yes, you need to use Kendo's DataSourceRequest object with its attribute .

```
using Kendo.MVC.UI;
using Kendo.MVC.Extensions;
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult KendoGridMyTeam([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
     ... 
    return Json(yourDataVariable.ToDataSource(request));
}
```

Comment: I'll just add that it wouldn't work on an ApiController, only a regular (MVC) Controller.

Comment: I'll also add that I just ran into this problem again and I find I answered my own problem two years ago!